# Tomb for Charles V (of france) and Jeanne de Bourbon in Saint Denis?

Tags: france, 14th-century

Can someone provide me with the location of the tomb for Charles V and Jeanne de Bourbon in Saint Denis ?

To be specific: I know that the tomb was located in the chapel of the virgin, but after it was destroyed the remaining figure of Charles was relocated. Where is it now ?

Comment: Did you do any preliminary research? "The tomb of Charles V and Jeanne de Bourbon in Saint Denis was destroyed in 1793 and its layout is only known today thanks to the watercolour by Gaignières (BnF). " [art tribune](http://www.thearttribune.com/A-fragment-of-Charles-V-s-tomb.html)

Comment: Sorry I guess the question was not clear, I edited the original post. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I stand corrected; [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_St_Denis#Bourbon_crypt) shows a [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_St_Denis#/media/File:Basilique_St._Denis_-_Gisantds_de_Bertrand_Du_Guesclin,_Charles_VI,_Isabeau_de_Baviere,_Louis_de_Sancerre,_Charles_V_le_Sage,_Jeanne_de_Bourbon.jpg) of Charles' burial.

Comment: What part of the Basilika is shown in the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, some of his bones were recovered and brought back to the basilique Saint-Denis, his heart is in the cathedral of Rouen and his bowels and guts in le Louvres, within his recumbent statues.

https://www.tombes-sepultures.com/crbst_378.html

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Sources to support your assertions would greatly improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you enter the basilica, walk down the far right side (south side).  Just before you get to the steps going up to the altar area, turn to your right, through the low wrought iron "fence" (now you're facing south; you'll see tombs of Charles Martel, Clovis, etc. on your right just as you enter this chapel area).  Charles V and Jeanne are in a grouping near the back of this chapel area. Good signage.